# How to show pdf file in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i just try to sample application for ios, android and web using react-native-web. Here i have to download a pdf file from server and while click the showpdf button the downloaded file need to open in both android application as well as windows browser also. for browser download i have used the following code

```
 fetch('http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf',{ 
      method: 'GET', 
      mode: 'no-cors',
      responseType: 'blob', // important
    headers: {       
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },})
            .then(response => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', item.pdfFileName);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        this.setState({
          pdf_url:url
        });
```

after download i need to open this pdf file. please help if anyone know this. thanks.

Comment: window.open(url);

Comment: url- here i want browser downloaded path

Answer (score 9):

You could use `<iframe>` to preview the PDF directly in your page, setting the src attribute to pdf_url. `window.open(pdf_url)` is also an option as mentioned above, but it'll require the user to have adblocker/pop-up blocker turned off.

In your `render()`:

```
{pdf_url && <iframe src={pdf_url} />}
```

See [MDN for multiple ways to display files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Using_object_URLs_to_display_PDF)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Very straight forward and resolves exactly the problem of viewing pdf within a browser in a cross-browser/ js framework/library manner.
did implement and it worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf library, using which you can simply display pdfs just like images

Here is online demo http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-pdf/

Comment: But, this example shows open the pdf through folder file selection. But i want 1. first button for download , 2. Preview button for show the pdf file thats it